# Solve Inequality for $ |x| $

Tags: inequality

Given $$\big|\frac{(x-2)}{(x+3)}\big| < 4,$$  solve for $x.$

\ My solution

$$|x - 2| < 4|x + 3|$$

Since,

$ |x - 2| \ge |x| - |2| $ and

$ |x + 3| \le |x| + |3| $ according to triangle inequality;

$|x| - |2| < 4|x| + 4|3| $

$-14 < 3|x|$

$|x| > \frac{-14}{3}$

Is this the final answer?

Comment: Might want to learn latex

Comment: You essentially derived an inequality B from an inequality A. All x solving B will solve A, but you haven't shown that those are *all* solutions. For the general case, solve the inequality by looking at $x$ in $[2, \infty)$, $(-3, 2)$, and $(-\infty, -3)$ (inequality is not defined at $-3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{x-2}{x+3}\right|<4$$
$$-4<\frac{x-2}{x+3}<4~~ |\cdot (x+3)^2\ne 0$$
$$-4(x+3)^2<(x-2)(x+3)<4(x+3)^2$$
$$\begin{cases}
-4(x+3)^2<(x-2)(x+3)\\
(x-2)(x+3)<4(x+3)^2
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
0<(x+3)((x-2)+4(x+3))\\
0<(x+3)(4(x+3)-x+2)
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
0<(x+3)(5x+10)\\
0<(x+3)(3x+14)
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
\left[\begin{array}{}x<-3\\ x>-2\end{array}\right.\\
\left[\begin{array}{}x<-\frac{14}{3}\\ x>-3\end{array}\right.
\end{cases}$$
So the final answer is $x\in(\infty;-\frac{14}{3})\cup(-2;\infty)$

Comment: Wow. Never expected such a clear decent explanation. Thanks a lot @AlexeyBurdin

Answer (score 1):

from the graph  $$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{x+3} = 1-\frac5{x+3}$$ you can see that it has vertical asymptote $x = 3$ and a horizontal one $y = 1.$  the function $f$ is decreasing on $\-infty, -3)$ and increasing on $-3, \infty).$

solving $f(x) = 4$  gives $x = -14/3$ and $f(x) = -4$ gives $x = -2.$

therefore $$ \left|\frac{x-2}{x+3} \right| < 4 \text{ for } -\infty < x < -14/3, -2 < x < \infty.$$